# H2databaseの接続エラーについて

Tags: sql, database

h2databaseの接続ができなくて困っています。

コンソール自体の起動はできて、　JDBC URL:jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
のテスト動作も問題なくおこなえますが、別のアドレスJDBC URL：jdbc:h2:~/terasolunaを指定すると、以下のようにログがでます。

```
一般エラー: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS
General error: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS [50000-78] HY000/50000 (ヘルプ)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 一般エラー: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS
General error: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS [50000-78] 
    at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:103) 
    at org.h2.message.Message.convert(Message.java:257) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:226) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:125) 
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:108) 
    at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:242) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108) 
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:87) 
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:57) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:625) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.test(WebThread.java:1028) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:440) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.processRequest(WebThread.java:184) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:239) 
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:194) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS 
    at org.h2.message.Message.getInternalError(Message.java:179) 
    at org.h2.table.TableData.addIndex(TableData.java:202) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:564) 
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:207) 
    ... 13 more
```

再度、やり直すたびに、ポート番号は特定してタスクを消去して競合しないようにはしていますが、考えられる原因はどのようなものがあありますでしょうか？

追加:h2db_init実行時のログ

```
C:\Users\hironori\Desktop\pleiades\workspace\terasoluna-spring-thin-blank\h2db>
ava -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/terasoluna -user sa -scrip
 terasoluna.script -showResults
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 一般エラー: java.lang.
untimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS
General error: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS [50000-78]
        at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:103)
        at org.h2.message.Message.convert(Message.java:257)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:226)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:125)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:108)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:242)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:87)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:57)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:319)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.run(RunScript.java:151)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS
        at org.h2.message.Message.getInternalError(Message.java:179)
        at org.h2.table.TableData.addIndex(TableData.java:202)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:564)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:207)
        ... 12 more
```

オプション追加実行後のログ

```
C:\Users\hironori\Desktop\pleiades\workspace\terasoluna-spring-thin-blank\h2db>j
ava -Dh2.check=false -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:~/terasoluna
 -user sa -script terasoluna.script -showResults
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: テーブル USERLIST が見
つかりません
Table USERLIST not found; SQL statement:
CREATE INDEX PUBLIC.IDX_USERLIST ON PUBLIC.USERLIST(ID) [42102-78]
        at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:103)
        at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:114)
        at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:77)
        at org.h2.schema.Schema.getTableOrView(Schema.java:348)
        at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateIndex.update(CreateIndex.java:60)
        at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.execute(MetaRecord.java:85)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:584)
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:207)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:125)
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:108)
        at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:242)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:87)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:57)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:319)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.run(RunScript.java:151)
        at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:94)
```

Comment: [このページ](http://terasoluna.osdn.jp/tutorial/server-web/Document/WebTutorial_2.2.html)の「(6) データベースの設定」は正しく実施しましたか？

Comment: 正しく実施しているのであれば、組み込みモードのH2データベースが`C:\Users\ユーザー名`などに作成されていないかチェックして、あればJDBC URLを`jdbc:h2:c:\Users\ユーザー名/terasoluna`のようにをフルパスで指定してみて下さい。

Comment: ファイルパスを指定して接続自体はできます。ただ現状として左側に“USERLIST”テーブルが出てこないという状態になっています。

Comment: であれば、スキーマかテーブルが作成されていないのかもしれません。h2db_init.batを実行して、その結果を教えて下さい。

Comment: 追記をしました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h2db_init.bat`の次の行に

```
java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url %H2URL% -user %H2USER% -script terasoluna.script -showResults
```

`-Dh2.check=false`というオプションを付加してから、実行したら結果が変わりませんか？

```
java -Dh2.check=false -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url %H2URL% -user %H2USER% -script terasoluna.script -showResults
```

Comment: -Dh2.check=false　追加後のログを追記しました。やはりUSERLIST テーブルが見つからないということですが、これ自体はどこの設定を変えるか考えられるところはありますでしょうか

Comment: H2コンソールにはログインできますか？できるのであれば、`terasoluna.script`の中身をコピーして、 SQLステートメントの入力欄に張り付けて直接実行してみて下さい。それでもエラーが出ますか？

Comment: (補足) このサイトにログを張り付ける時は、Ctrl+Kを押して、見やすい形式にして下さい。

Comment: エラー解消できてUSERLIST作成できました。コンソールへのログイン自体は可能でしたのでJDBC URLのパスを指定して、terasoluna.scriptをステートメントで実行しました。

Comment: 貼り付けの際の注意事項わざわざありがとうございました。以後気を付けます。

Comment: うまくいったのでしょうか？そうであれば、これはクローズしておいて下さい。ちなみに`-Dh2.check=false`は`java.lang.RuntimeException: rowcount remaining=-1 SYS`を回避するための対策であって、根本対策ではないかもしれません。H2のソースコードを読んで、これで例外がスローされることは無いということは分かりましたが。